# Apply CSS to multiple elements in variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
var $e1 = $('#e1');
var $e2 = $('#e2');
var $e3 = $('#e3');
```

This doesn't work:

```
var $all = [$e1, $e2, $e3];
$($all).css('background', '#ff0000');
```

How should I do this, while reusing `$el1`, `$el2`, `$el3`?

I don't want to do:

```
$('#e1, #e2, #e3')
```

This is probably very simple to do, but I don't know what to search for to find out.

Comment: Why don't you want to do $('#e1, #e2, #e3') if I may ask ?

Comment: The `$`-prefix in variable names is for jQuery objects. Don't use it for regular arrays, it will only confuse you.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Can you explain a little better when I should and shouldn't start a variable with $ according to "jQuery style".

Comment: This is an array: `[1, 2, 3]`. This is a jQuery object: `$('div')`. When choosing a variable name, you use the $-prefix for those variables which values are jQuery objects. For instance: `var x = true; var y = [1,2,3]; var $z = $('#z');`

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Thanks, I will try to do this from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var $all = $e1.add($e2).add($e3);
```

Or this (looks a little obtuse, but it's the correct way - you have to extract the node from the jQuery object first with `[0]`):

```
var $all = $([$e1[0], $e2[0], $e3[0]]);
```

---

**Note:** in my examples, `$all` is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to wrap it again like this: `$($all)`. Just do:

```
$all.css('background', '#ff0000');
```

Comment: `[0]` is what I was really looking for. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: even better:

```
var $e1 = $('#e1');
var $e2 = $('#e2');
var $e3 = $('#e3');
var all = $e1.add($e2).add($e3);
all.css('background', '#ff0000');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$e1.add($e2).add($e3)
```

is another way of merging different elements/jQuery objects.

Reference: [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
wrap array in jQuery instance and iterate through its elements

```
all = [$e1, $e2, $e3];

$(all).each(function(index, element){
   element.css('background', '#ff0000');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't want to use a selector, apply the style to each element of the array.

```
for(i = 0; i < $all.length; i++)
    $all[i].css('background', '#ff0000');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do what you have in your example:

```
var $all = [$e1, $e2, $e3],
    i = $all.length;

for(; i--;) {
    $all[i].css('background', '#f00');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you ca do just this:

```
$(deleteBtn).add(copyBtn).add(moveBtn).css('background', 'white');
```

As it says here http://api.jquery.com/add/